# It won't work, I want the USER to enter the Username under that statement and then the password under that

Tags: java, authentication

I want them to enter the username and then the password then if they have entered the wrong username or password I want them to enter it again.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Username {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("Enter Username:");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Enter Password:");
        String passWord = myInput.nextLine();
        String userName = myInput.nextLine();

        while (!userName.equals("Morel"))
        while (!passWord.equals("Deacon")) {
            System.out.println("wrong username or Password, Please try again:");

            userName = myInput.nextLine();
            passWord = myInput.nextLine();

        }

        System.out.println("Welcome");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's bad logic. Nesting while loops for input isn't a good idea. It should be more like (in pseudo-code):

```
while(true) {
    username = myInput.nextline();
    password = myInput.nextline();
    if (username == "morel") && (password == "deacon") {
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: use `equals()` not `==`

Answer (score 2):

You've inversed username and password.

Try:

```
String userName = myInput.nextLine();
String passWord = myInput.nextLine();
```